# Can we [table] this tag, and use [tables] instead?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

I saw the [table](/questions/tagged/table) tag on [this, now deleted, off-topic question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357680/622284). I figure, since [tables are now supported in markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/622284), we should be able to merge [table](/questions/tagged/table) into [tables](/questions/tagged/tables), especially considering the latter has a tag wiki and more questions.

All questions tagged with [table](/questions/tagged/table) concern the creation of tables in posts.

I propose:

- We create a synonym from [table](/questions/tagged/table) to [tables](/questions/tagged/tables)
- We replace the [table](/questions/tagged/table) tag on the 6 questions tagged with it with [tables](/questions/tagged/tables) (or a moderator merges them)

Sound fair enough?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [tag synonym page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tables/synonyms) (emphasis mine):

> If you know of common, alternate spellings or phrasings for this tag, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or **“sock” for socks**.

This is *literally* one of the reasons tag synonyms exist. We should most definitely synonymize [table](/questions/tagged/table) to [tables](/questions/tagged/tables).

---

#### Update

[tables](/questions/tagged/tables) has been successfully [voted into becoming a synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tables/synonyms) of [tables](/questions/tagged/tables).

Comment: I suggested the synonym, it just needs votes from enough people with a score of 5 or more in [tag:tables]

Comment: @KodosJohnson it only needs one additional vote atm.