# Keyboard shortcut to answer a question doesn't work if you have already posted an answer

Tags: bug, answers, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

Found this out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support), where I've posted quite a few answers.  If you've already posted an answer to a question, you cannot use the <kbd>A</kbd> key to answer it again; you have to use the "Add another answer" button.  I answer questions frequently and almost always use the <kbd>A</kbd> key, so this is quite annoying.  Can we fix this, please?

Comment: This also applies when answering your own question, you have to click the button.