# "Add an answer" button is sometimes missing

Tags: bug, answers, google-chrome, action-buttons

The "Add an answer" button is sometimes missing. Screenshot from [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/178179):

[image]

though most of the time I do see the "Add an answer" button (using the same computer + web browser, namely Chrome on Microsoft Windows 7):

[image]

I don't know how to repro. Happened to me several times on [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/178179) a few days ago.

Comment: Is this also the case when you disable this darkmoden extension?

Comment: @Luuklag I haven't tried it. Will do next time I see the issue, but it'd be surprising to me if this was the issue as I've used this darkmode flag for approximately one year and it never hides elements (at worse just making text challenging/impossible to read).

Comment: I agree with @Luuklag.  Look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeo7i.png) screenshot, Franck, but I'll wait a bit and see.

Comment: Oh now it's back again...

Comment: @Ollie see it's weird, on and off :-)

Comment: Found other bug while testing it: if the question has over 30 answers, you won't see "Add Another Answer" even after having an answer there.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard Looks like that's inconsistent too, I'm still seeing it.

Comment: Hey Franck, try something:  Go to the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox); see if the button only appears on a page *other* than the first.