# Search doesn't space out tags in a post

Tags: bug, design, search

I went and did a [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A798831+is%3Aanswer) for my answers, and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support/357006#357006) answer, which was reported as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and then marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), isn't showing the tags as spaced out:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Another example:

[image]

Can we fix that?

<sup>Please don't mark this post [bugstatus-completed](/questions/tagged/bugstatus-completed) when it's fixed.</sup>

Comment: Ah, thanks Glorfindel, didn't realize that would auto-redirect to your own answers.

Comment: That's a [common mistake](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/7092/revisions) ...

Comment: It’s worth noting that tags that aren’t spaced out in search are written like `[meta-tag:bug][meta-tag:status-completed]`, and tags that _are_ spaced out are written like `[meta-tag:bug] [meta-tag:status-completed]` (note the space). I don’t know how exactly the Markdown is converted into a text-only representation (used in search), but adding a space after each `[tag:`…`]` and `[meta-tag:`…`]` should be sufficient. Double spaces will be merged by the browser anyway.

Comment: So this is status by design. Could you consider adding your comment as an answer @user289905

Comment: @Luuklag Not sure what substance such an answer would have. We’d need to edit every single answer. I realize that my previous comment may have been misleading: _“adding a space after each […] should be sufficient”_ — I mean _Stack Exchange staff_ should add the space in the text-only representation. Of course, users adding a space would also work, but that would involve editing every single answer that uses tag formatting and being aware of it in the future. A fix to this bug would be SE team changing how tag formatting gets represented in search. So this should perhaps be a feature request.

Comment: @user289905 agreed that this should be a FR, but your comment suffices that this is not a bug but status-by-design.