# Markdown preview doesn't match post

Tags: bug, editor, markdown-preview

What I wrote:

```
| Road class                             | [Syntax explanation](https://sites.google.com/site/roadnumberingsystems/home/general-information/legend) |
| -------------------------------------- | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| European road                          | E-\[0-9\]<2-3>                                                                                           |
| Motorway (Autopista)                   | AP-\[0-9\]<1-2>                                                                                          |
| Expressway (Autovía)                   | A-\[0-9\]<1-2>                                                                                           |
| Radial motorway                        | R\[1-5\]                                                                                                 |
| National road (Carretera Nacional)     | N-\`Roman\`{a};N-\[0-9\]<3>{a}                                                                           |
| Regional road (Carretera Comarcal)     | C-\[0-9\]<3-4>{a}                                                                                       
| Community road                         | [see region table](https://sites.google.com/site/roadnumberingsystems/home/countries/spain#eregions)     |
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66lsf.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpsLF.png
```

Preview:

[image]

Actual post after saving the edit:

[image]

Comment: I think this is due to the bug I reported here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596/299995. I think it's because the imgur sources at the bottom are right after the table. Try adding a newline between the table and imgur links.

Comment: The comment by @Kodos is correct, a newline is required between the post and its URL List. Adding one newline (there are 2 by default) makes the output the same. See [Sandbox Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359001/282094), and a [screenshot of Sandbox post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI9nM.png).

Comment: thanks, correct, just reporting preview discrepancy.

Comment: You need a newline between the table and **anything**, not just URL sources. This table was mangled by being followed by `------` on the next line: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71144235/revisions

Comment: @JackDeeth thanks, correct, just reporting preview discrepancy.