# Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, tables

When I edited an answer to add a second markdown table, both the first and second tables rendered correctly in preview, but the *second* table does not render. I've waited about 10 minutes in case there is some cache/refresh issue, and also tried both Chrome (87.0.4280.88 64-bit win10) and Firefox (84.0.1 64-bit win10) with equivalent result.

I think the actual problem is that the preview works even if there is *no blank line before the table header row*.

**Simple table (looks good in preview) but no blank line before table header**:
| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| -------- | ------------ | ----------- |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |

**Simple table (looks good in preview) with blank line before table header**:

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |

**Simple table (looks good in preview) but no blank line before table header**:
| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| -------- | ------------ | ----------- |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |

**Simple table (looks good in preview) with blank line before table header**:

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |

My earlier thought process is here, OK to stop reading at this point:

https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7320/35022

**Image of Second table as seen in edit preview (correct)**:
[image: as seen in edit preview]

**Image of Second table as rendered in posted answer (incorrect)**:
[image: as rendered in answer]

**Second table as rendered here (looks correct in preview)**:

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [20V -> 5V -> USB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/490017) | 2020-03-31 00:13:44 | still open |
| [What is a readhead?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/454363) | 2019-08-23 19:44:14 | still open |

**Second table as rendered here, again (looks correct in preview)**:

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [20V -> 5V -> USB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/490017) | 2020-03-31 00:13:44 | still open |
| [What is a readhead?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/454363) | 2019-08-23 19:44:14 | still open |

Both instances of this table in markdown look correct in the preview here on meta... let me see if they render correctly once posted...

After posting, both instances look incorrect. Is the table malformed?

**Second table as rendered here (looks correct in preview)**:

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [20V -> 5V -> USB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/490017) | 2020-03-31 00:13:44 | still open |
| [What is a readhead?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/454363) | 2019-08-23 19:44:14 | still open |

**Simple table without links (looks good in preview)**:

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |

**Simple table without links, missing space before vertical bars (looks good in preview)**:

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |

**Simple table (looks good in preview) but no blank line before table header**:
| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| -------- | ------------ | ----------- |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |

**Simple table (looks good in preview) with blank line before table header**:

| Question | Date Created | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |
| xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx |

Can it please be made so that the preview also doesn't render tables if there's no blank line between the table header and the line of text above it, so it matches the actual post rendering?

Comment: There needs to be an empty line above the table header. Currently there’s the line “These have been dealt with by adding additional tags:” directly above it.

Comment: @user289905 want to make that an answer? I think you're right, I just now fixed up my original post. Leaving this here as a signpost for others.

Comment: Weird, I reported a bug [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support/357596#357596) but in that case it was broken **in preview** but working after it was saved.

Comment: This has already been reported here: [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596/289905). Dang, @KodosJohnson beat me to it.

Comment: disregard my comment above, it is the same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown preview doesn't match post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358999/markdown-preview-doesnt-match-post)

Comment: @KodosJohnson Don't think that this is a duplicate of that. That one's a completely different bug, regarding line breaks *after* a table; this one is about line breaks *before* a table. While they may be the same cause, I'd leave those as two separate reports since they're two different bugs; if they turn out to be the same, an SE employee can close this.

Comment: I just run into the same issue when composing the answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/686067/101063. In case it matters was using Google Chome ``Version 118.0.5993.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)`` under Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Asked 3 yrs 1 month ago. Still a problem today. I ran into the same issue [here]: (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/638886/sample-size-vs-replicates-for-comparison-tests). Google Chrome Version 110.0.5481.78 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Win 10 Enterprise 1909 build 18363.2274.