# Table Markdown content in a question breaks only when posted

Tags: bug, questions, markdown, markdown-preview, tables

A user on Puzzling.SE reported [this apparent bug](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7193/71652):

> This is what it looked like in the preview thing in the edit mode,

> [image]
>
> Then, this is what it looked like in question.
>
> [image]

We already know that a broken code block or table can be fixed by adding some newlines around the broken thing, yet the current behavior is still a UX problem:

- Preview != actual post.
- When something seems to work (by looking at the preview) but actually doesn't (in the actual post), it gives more frustration than when it doesn't work in preview.

---

This apparently [has been a known issue for over three months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596/419414), but it's still not fixed. (Also, it's so hard to find a duplicate bug report...)

Comment: There probably isn't a real linebreak before and between the tables. This issue was reported in the alpha test of the stacks editor. Probably its root cause is within the preview renderer.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360319/361484

Comment: Already reported: [Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359192/289905).