# Some Markdown tables incorrectly omit an entire column in the rendered post, but display correctly in the preview

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, tables

**This is not a duplicate of the following posts:**

- [Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359192/markdown-table-preview-does-not-detect-missing-blank-line-before-table-header) - that question is reporting a different issue, a problem with tables *without blank lines* before the table header, while this is about tables with specific content that *do* correctly have blank lines above them.
- [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) - none of the answers to that announcement post address the issue here. The answers cited in the comments - [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596/361484) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357009/361484) - are reporting different issues from the one reported here: the first one is the same as the above question, and the second is about quotes and table *rows* while this one is about *columns*. While the latter issue has the same workaround as here, it's still a different issue in the system.

While this question originally reported two problems, one of which was the same as the above first one, this has since been edited to only cover the other problem, which is **not covered in any of the above posts**.

---

At times, there is a significant difference between how a post in the editor preview and the actual post displays Markdown tables. One such issue was reported on the announcement post on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596/397219). However, almost a year down the line, it's still a problem, and I frequently find myself editing posts because of the previewer and the actual content being different. Is there any kind of ETA on this being fixed?

Here's another such issue. I will include the Markdown in code format, then the Markdown as I have posted it, and then screenshots of the preview and the actual post, in that order.

Markdown:

```markdown
**Id**|**Value**
:-----:|:-----:
7E38AD4A-4C6E-40D9-B805-08C1F4EE14D0|1,370
E48A0A4A-6E6C-41A8-B379-0E14452938C6|1,200
```

Table:

| **Value** |
| --- |
| 7E38AD4A-4C6E-40D9-B805-08C1F4EE14D0 |
| E48A0A4A-6E6C-41A8-B379-0E14452938C6 |

Preview:
[image]

Actual Post:
[image]

I am sure there are other scenarios too. As you can see, the preview shows **both** columns, but in the post it only shows one column, with only the first declared column header, and both values in the column (it treats it like one full table cell with the pipe included).

The problem here isn't that the Markdown needs correcting, but that there's an inconsistency. The preview and the actual post should be the same. If that means that the preview shows the same as post currently do, that's a fix. But the two can be vastly different, and that's confusing (especially for those unfamiliar with Markdown and that when they edit the post it looks "ok").

As stated above, the duplicate suggestions do *not* duplicate the matter where an entire column is missing and the wrong header is given to the one that is displayed.

Comment: I get this bug with [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/90585/1787), too. The preview renders the tables properly, but not the rendered post. Interestingly, only 1 header + 1 row tables render properly.

Comment: What happens if you prepend a '|' in front of the first non-header table row? That fixed the issue for me; cf. [this diff](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/90585/revisions).

Comment: It does, the point, however, is that the preview and post are different, @Geremia .