# Markdown tables render differently in preview and post

Tags: bug, markdown, tables

I recently made a Markdown table as part of an [answer to a question on Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/105203/52196). Here's the text:

```
***R<sub>g</sub>* protein C (Å)**|***R<sub>g</sub>* protein D (Å)**
-----|-----
15|5.5
11.5|2.4
12.2|13.3
20.6|14.2
20.2|17.2
11.2|12.6
15.2|17.8
9.3|9.9
10.8|10.1
14.9|8.4
14.2|10.4
8.2|4.8
```

When previewing my answer, the table renders correctly:

[image]

After submitting my answer, the first column is lost:

[image]

I can correct this by adding <kbd>|</kbd> to to the beginning of each row.

```
|***R<sub>g</sub>* protein A (Å)**|***R<sub>g</sub>* protein B (Å)**
|-----|-----
|10.1|11.1
|10.2|11.2
|10.1|11.1
|10.3|11
|10.9|11.7
|9.8|10.8
|9.9|10.9
|10|11
|10.3|11.2
|10.1|10.8
|10|11.5
|9.5|11.1
```

Notwithstanding correct table syntax, I expect the preview and the post to be identical. I suspect the bug in this case has to do with my combination of tables with other Markdown elements, though I'm not sure.

Comment: This has been reported before: [Some Markdown tables incorrectly omit an entire column in the rendered post, but display correctly in the preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371475/some-markdown-tables-incorrectly-omit-an-entire-column-in-the-rendered-post-but)

Comment: I don't think the first `|` is optional. The preview renderer isn't compliant and shouldn't render a table when the the first `|` is missing. I assume that is the bug you want have fixed?