# Incomplete table Markdown causes preview to appear fine while it's broken when posted

Tags: bug, status-review, markdown-preview, tables

A usual one line table has the below syntax:

```txt
|this is one line table|
|----|
```

and render as:

| this is one line table |
| --- |

If we omit the vertical lines:

```txt
|this is one line table|
----
```

It is rendered the same *while editing*, but after saving the post, the render is different and the table is gone.

### |this is one line table|

To see this more clearly, click [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/372897/edit).

From the user's perspective, they should have the same result, although the syntax is not correct.

Comment: There’s a few rendering differences because Stack Exchange uses two different Markdown parsers: a client-side one for live rendering and a server-side one for server-side rendering (IIRC). See [the Formatting Sandbox](/a/357003/289905) and [Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header](/q/359192/289905).

Comment: Other related markdown table issues: [Markdown preview doesn't match post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358999/markdown-preview-doesnt-match-post) and [Some Markdown tables incorrectly omit an entire column in the rendered post, but display correctly in the preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371475/some-markdown-tables-incorrectly-omit-an-entire-column-in-the-rendered-post-but)