# Getting a code formatting error when I try to post this question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, asking-questions, code-formatting

When I try to post this question to Stack Overflow I get the following error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I have tried multiple different ways to indent the code properly, but it will not take it. The code looks correct to me. Do you see something that I don't? I also removed all semicolons from the rest of the text thinking it may be causing it, but that did not work. I really wish the questions page on Stack Overflow would point out exactly where the problem is located.

> I have two xlsx files that have multiple tabs. I need to compare values in each tab based on the tab name. (e.g. sheet1 in file1 needs to be compared with sheet1 in file2 and so on). When I use the following code, it will only compare and write first sheet. Please help me figure out why all tabs do not get compared.
>
> import pandas as pd
> import numpy as np
>
> df1 = pd.read_excel('test_1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
> df2 = pd.read_excel('test_2.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
>
> with pd.ExcelWriter('./Excel_diff.xlsx') as writer:
> for sheet, df1 in df1.items():
> # check if sheet is in the other Excel file
> if sheet in df2:
> df2 = df2[sheet]
> comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
>
> ```
>            print(comparison_values)
>
>            rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
>            for item in zip(rows, cols):
>                df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]], df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])
>
>            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, header=True)
> ```
>
> The test_1 file is set up as follows.
>
> Sheet1
> |test 1|test 2|test 3|
> |------|------|------|
> |1     |1     |1     |
> |1     |1     |1     |
> |1     |1     |1     |
>
> Sheet2
> |test 1|test 2|test 3|
> |------|------|------|
> |3     |3     |3     |
> |3     |3     |3     |
> |3     |3     |3     |
>
> The test_2 file is set up as follows.
>
> Sheet1
> |test 1|test 2|test 3|
> |------|------|------|
> |2     |2     |2     |
> |2     |2     |2     |
> |2     |2     |2     |
>
> Sheet2
> |test 1|test 2|test 3|
> |------|------|------|
> |4     |4     |4     |
> |4     |4     |4     |
> |4     |4     |4     |
>
> **Here is the output I want that shows the difference in values by sheet name.**
>
> Sheet1
> |test 1|test 2|test 3|
> |------|------|------|
> |1-->2 |1-->2 |1-->2 |
> |1-->2 |1-->2 |1-->2 |
> |1-->2 |1-->2 |1-->2 |
>
> Sheet2
> |test 1|test 2|test 3|
> |------|------|------|
> |3-->4 |3-->4 |3-->4 |
> |3-->4 |3-->4 |3-->4 |
> |3-->4 |3-->4 |3-->4 |

Comment: I assume it is detecting the test files as code, put those in code blocks as well

Comment: Thank you so much! I was following the table format instructions and they looked really nice. They are not as nice when I put them in code blocks, but it finally took my question. Thank you!!

Comment: if you wanted tables, you have to align the items properly. Over here they look like one long line each, but each row in the table should be put on its own row.

Comment: yes, I noticed that too. It is very strange because they question preview area shows them as nicely formatted tables. I wonder why it displays differently once it is posted?

Comment: the `-->` in your table are likely the culprit. Replace them with a word, not other symbols.  And  before your tables  insert a blank line. Currently your titles are directly above each table which is misunderstood by the server-side parser. White space / blank lines are key

Comment: @rene you're right! The --> I was using to designate the change in values was messing everything up. I changed that to the word 'to' and it is now working beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: You could use `&rarr;` or Unicode "→" instead of "-->"

Comment: Oooh la la! That looks so much nicer than the -->. Thank you for the suggestion @This_is_NOT_a_forum .

Comment: Seems like [you fixed the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72035588)

Comment: @bobble Yes! :) I was able to fix the problem with the help of everyone above. I am unsure if I should delete this comment or leave it in case it is helpful for others.

Comment: It's a Good Idea to put test data and expected output into code blocks. That makes it easier to run your code (and modified versions of your code created by the answerers) with the test data, and to verify that the actual output exactly matches the expected out.

Comment: That the preview incorrectly displays tables correctly when there's no blank line between it and the text above it is a known bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359192/markdown-table-preview-does-not-detect-missing-blank-line-before-table-header

Comment: I can reproduce the bug.
I went to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask and pasted
`|test 1|test 2|\n
|------|------|\n
|1-->2 |1-->2 |\n
|1-->2 |1-->2 |\n
|1-->2 |1-->2 |\n`.
Then I clicked *Review your question* and got back the 
*not properly formatted as code* buggy error message.
If I instead leave out the third row of the table, I get
*Your question is ready to publish!*.
* ~ *
This is yet another example of how crappy & useless this senseless filter is.
A *table* is ***not*** a *code block*.
How hard can it be to understand such a simple thing?