# Cannot post question - 'Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code'

Tags: bug, code-formatting, tables

I am trying to post a question to Stack Overflow (and also relevant on a few other sites) but am met with the following message:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I'm not entirely sure why given that I've followed the formatting where I believe it is required. My question is formatted as follows:

---

I would like to {do something with this data}:

| Country | Year | LifeExp | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chile | 2000 | 77.3 | 7.79e+10 |
| Chile | 2000 | 77.3 | 7.79e+10 |
| Chile | 2000 | 77.3 | 7.79e+10 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Zimbabwe | 2013 | 58.0 | 1.55e+10 |
| Zimbabwe | 2014 | 59.2 | 1.59e+10 |
| Zimbabwe | 2015 | 60.7 | 1.63e+10 |

Ideally, I would like to {do more stuff with this data}.

```
gdp_data['GDP%'] = 0
gdp_country = gdp_data[gdp_data['Country'] == 'Chile']
gdp_data['GDP%'] = gdp_country['GDP'].pct_change()
```

Is there a (correct and) more efficient way?

Comment: The most likely cause is that the Markdown table is being recognized as code. Chances are that the code detector hasn't been updated since support for tables was added to the system, and that the developers overlooked doing so since higher-reputation users are exempt from the filter and it's not enabled at all on all but four sites in the network.

Comment: Also, to the close voter who voted this as "site-specific" - the code filter is enabled on four sites, not only Stack Overflow. Take another look at the usage guidance for the close reason in the dialog.

Comment: Thank you @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog. Do you know if this issue will be fixed?

Comment: @Sonic just a thought, it might be worth documenting which sites in e.g. the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/295232)? (I don't know which ones ...)

Comment: @Glorfindel: The relevant Q&A: [What sites have the code formatting filter enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313385/335251)

Comment: Voting to leave open based on Sonic's comment. If someone's confident the cause of the problem is the table consider retagging this as `bug`.

Comment: @bad_coder not 100% confident, but I can remember 2 other situations where a table seems to have caused this issue (one a question on meta, and the other my own question iirc)

Comment: @bad_coder https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378308/getting-a-code-formatting-error-when-i-try-to-post-this-question-on-stack-overfl#comment1262592_378308 another question where tables were triggering an improperly formatted code error

Comment: It would be great if you would include the exact Markdown that triggered the error.

I copied the Markdown from
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/387101/edit

I then went to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
and pasted the Markdown unchanged.

Upon pressing *Review your question*,  I got

*Your question is ready to publish!*

Conclusion: I couldn't reproduce the error message you reported here.

Comment: @Henke I was able to post the question later in the day with _zero_ changes made to the content. Hence, I'm not sure why the error was thrown at the time. I'm sorry I can't be of more help in reproducing it.

Comment: Thanks for responding!
Theoretically, the reason could be that "someone" corrected a bug in the filter.
But since you couldn't reproduce the bug later *the same day*, that doesn't seem very
plausible.
The only *plausible* explanation I can see is that this bug occurs with some randomness.
If so, you must have had some bad luck when trying to post the first time.
Someone with a sense of responsibility should definitely do some serious work
to correct this buggy and crappy "feature"! Sigh.