# Tables just became broken in Markdown preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview, tables

I just tried to insert a table while writing a post but it appeared broken in the preview. I used the basic example shown in the "formatting tips" to confirm:

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
```

And here's what I see in the preview:

[image: Broken table]

I even tried to edit an existing post that had tables in it and all the tables were broken in the preview (although they looked fine in the live post).

To test this, you can simply edit this question and look at the preview of the following table.

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Comment: ...Yep, you're certainly right. I'm seeing the same thing if I try to edit your post (or make a new post) containing that exact table formatting.

Comment: While we are fixing this, can we also take care of these longstanding bugs? 
[Markdown preview doesn't match post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358999/markdown-preview-doesnt-match-post), [Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359192/markdown-table-preview-does-not-detect-missing-blank-line-before-table-header)

Comment: @CaveJohnson A part of me tells me this bug came about from a faulty attempt to fix those bugs.

Comment: @Sonic very unlikely, as neither of those bugs even have [tag:status-review] on them. Unless SE reverted their recent decision to first put bugs and requests into review, and back to the wild "Fix what you see" which didn't work well. (one bug fixed every few months, totally randomly.)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Developers aren't restricted to only completing escalated tasks, and it's up to them whether they want to tag as under review or planned before completing. If they stumble upon a meta report, they have the ability, both technically and procedurally, to fix it.

Comment: @Sonic sure, but that's just very rare. They do have internal "TO DO" list, which consists of bugs and feature requests marked for review. And those two bugs mentioned here aren't trivial to fix, so it is unlikely a developer will spend time of them outside of that internal list, which is very long already.

Answer (score 10):

This has been fixed

| if you | view this post |
| --- | --- |
| in edit mode | with preview |
| it should look | just right |

Comment: This problem (preview only) still effects History Stack Exchange (noticed yesterday and a new answer today). [united states - What is the story behind the tall Northern offshoot on the West Virginia map? - History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/69938/38607) Works when saved.

Comment: Nor in law, travel and expatriates.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ELL.SE same deal

Comment: Good job! But...what about regional sites?
The bug is still reproduced on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: We have same issue on meta https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12136/

Comment: We had a caching issue because of which the fix was not deployed correctly and the old version was still in use. We fixed it now - thank you all for catching the problem!