# Edit the Formatting Help Page to include Markdown syntax for Tables

Tags: feature-request, markdown, help, tables

[New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/259305) has not yet been documented in the [Formatting help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), as a result, many users across the SE network are still displaying tables with images, which are invisible to visually impaired users.  To be considerate and kind to them, please edit the aboved linked help page so that users know how to typeset table.

On Meta.SE, we have a "Tables" tab, so that users might be aware of this new feature.  However, on other sites like Math.SE, there's no such feature.  As a result, adding information about the Markdown syntax for tables in this help page is the easiest option.

[image: table options on edit box on Meta.SE]

Meta.SE edit box has "Tables" option.

[image: table options on edit box on Math.SE]

Math.SE edit box doesn't have "Tables" option.

Comment: The version of the Help is inconsistent. On [Stack Overflow Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/editing-help#tables) one doesn't have the *Helper Bar* and needs to go into the Advanced Help to see a limited explanation (with a helpful link), which is the [same as MSE's help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help); except we have the Helper Bar (pop-down help). --- The ***local*** advanced help should be longer, and the pop-down help should be available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the question mark at top right of the edit box.

[image]

Comment: Thus lacks a freehand circle.