# "Don't show this to me again" button for the "Are you sure you want to answer this question" popups

Tags: feature-request, design, popups

There are some questions (e.g, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) one and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) one) where I have provided a lot of answers and may provide more.  Each and every time, though, I get a popup saying:

[image]

Or:

[image]

This becomes very annoying after the third or fourth time.  Instead of outright not showing these, I would like to have a "Don't show this to me again" button on these popups, just like with the [Asking a good question modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVB73.png).  These are good tips, and so are the ones contained in the aforementioned modal, but they get irritating after a while, especially for old hands.

Comment: I think they could be vastly improved with the addition of a friendly paper clip.