# Table markup shows incorrectly in preview

Tags: bug, tables

When previewing a table that does *not* have the necessary linefeed before it, the preview shows up as if the table will render properly, but the eventual table does not.
|some|table|
|-|-|
|here is my|table that will not render|
|but it renders|in the preview below|

To verify this, click "edit" and look at the preview below - it will look like a nice table!

Here's an image of the preview for me:
[image: View of table previewing nicely]

This occurs on other stacks (I noticed it on Board Games, if it matters).  On Chrome, Version 88.0.4324.104 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596/295232

Comment: Yeah, just finally found that one... didn't come up in my first search, which is ... odd.

Comment: There's so many bug reports there, it took me quite a while too.

Comment: It's almost like a single post's answers isn't the best place for bug reports... >.<