# Is there a way to make a table with many lines in a cell?

Tags: support, markdown, tables

In [this question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/27057/12937), I want to make this table:

[image: Table with mutiline cells]

Is there a way to make a table having many lines in a cell?

Comment: See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357008/571958) with all kinds of different formatting inside tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Feeling Bad About Feeling Bad (Self-Loathing)** - Excessive self-criticism - Anxious/Neurotic behavior - Suppression of emotions - Engage in a lot of fake niceness/politeness - Feeling as though something is wrong with you | **Feeling Bad About Feeling Good (Guilt)** - Chronic guilt and feeling as though you [don’t deserve happiness](https://markmanson.net/how-to-be-happy) - Constant comparison of yourself to others - Feeling as though something *should* be wrong, even if everything is great - Unnecessary criticism and negativity |
| **Feeling Good About Feeling Bad (Self-Righteousness)** - Moral indignation - Condescension towards others - Feeling as though you deserve something others don’t - Seeking out a constant sense of powerlessness and victimization | **Feeling Good About Feeling Good (Ego/Narcissism)** - Self-congratulatory - Chronically overestimate yourself; a delusionally-positive self-perception - Unable to handle failure or rejection - Avoids confrontation or discomfort - Constant state of self-absorption |

```
|||
|--|--|
|**Feeling Bad About Feeling Bad (Self-Loathing)**<ul><li>Excessive self-criticism</li><li>Anxious/Neurotic behavior</li><li>Suppression of emotions</li><li>Engage in a lot of fake niceness/politeness</li><li>Feeling as though something is wrong with you</li></ul>|**Feeling Bad About Feeling Good (Guilt)**<ul><li>Chronic guilt and feeling as though you [don’t deserve happiness](https://markmanson.net/how-to-be-happy)</li><li>Constant comparison of yourself to others</li><li>Feeling as though something *should* be wrong, even if everything is great</li><li>Unnecessary criticism and negativity</li></ul>|
|**Feeling Good About Feeling Bad (Self-Righteousness)**<ul><li>Moral indignation</li><li>Condescension towards others</li><li>Feeling as though you deserve something others don’t</li><li>Seeking out a constant sense of powerlessness and victimization</li></ul>|**Feeling Good About Feeling Good (Ego/Narcissism)**<ul><li>Self-congratulatory</li><li>Chronically overestimate yourself; a delusionally-positive self-perception</li><li>Unable to handle failure or rejection</li><li>Avoids confrontation or discomfort</li><li>Constant state of self-absorption</li>/ul>|
```

See more: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/260800)

Comment: The other answer explains just fine how to achieve this.

Comment: but isn't that having the exact code is preferable?

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard The other answer doesn't have a link to more information and while it is correct, it does the bare minimum to answer the question. I think this answer is better.

Comment: @Ooker If you want the lists center-aligned to match you image example, adjust the divider row below the header (`|--|--|`) to be `|:--:|:--:|`.

Answer (score 8):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| yes, with HTML |  |

Markdown for that table:

```
| | |
|-|-|
| yes,<br/>with HTML | |
```

Comment: Maybe add how to create an unordered list with html. it is not trivial and messy as you need to keep stuff on a single line.

Comment: PSA: In the new editor, this will break when switching between Markdown and RT modes. So, one needs to be extra careful with it [until better support is (hopefully) added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364769/348196).

Comment: @rene That's a matter of adding some `<ul></ul>` combinations, but the formatting starts looking really weird if you do that on SE.

Comment: @Mast yeah. I know, I tried, I gave up when I added the 2nd cell and instead left a comment here.

Comment: @rene Well, to be fair, those aren't really unordered lists in the screenshot anyway. So, just using `-` would probably suffice.

Comment: @41686d6564 but ... the semantic web ... oh fine