# Table nested in a list item renders in preview, but not when saved

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, tables

I have just edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20981676/3840170).  My edit added markup like this:

0. list item
   | a | b |
   |:--|:--|
   | 0 | 1 |
   | 2 | 3 |

The above renders as a table in preview, but not when the answer is saved.

Comment: The problem is not with the table being nested in a list item. You just need a line break above the table.

Comment: I can't answer that. Note that the bug is _not_ that the table is not rendered after you save the edit. The standard is that the blank line is needed for the markdown to work. The actual bug is that the preview behaves differently (i.e., renders it as a table when it shouldn't). See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support/357596#comment1194747_357596) and the ones above it for more context.