# Is it possible to not embolden table headers?

Tags: feature-request, support, markdown, tables

When creating a table, all headers seem to be emboldened by default:

| Header 1 | Header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Sample | Sample |

However, this isn't always desirable since tables can simply house data in a easy to read format, for example:

> ###### Animals that *may* bite...
>
> | Dog | Cat | Bird |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Crocodile | Lion | Piranha |
> | ... | ... | ... |

This puts emphasis on *dog*, *cat* and *bird* since they are the only values emboldened. The only way to prevent this, that I've found, is a work around, and it's not that pretty:

> ###### Animals that *may* bite...
>
> |  |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Dog | Cat | Bird |
> | Crocodile | Lion | Piranha |
> | ... | ... | ... |

Notice the empty header values.

---

Is there a way, universal to Stack Exchange sites that would prevent the emboldening of table headers? If the answer is no, then can we get this as a feature?

Comment: Nope - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357093/284336

Comment: @Catija seems like it would be great to bring that comment over as an answer here placing emphasis on the statement "*The official table extension specification requires a table header and we absolutely want to stick to a (de facto) standard and avoid rolling our own.*", would you concur?

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not directly answer this question, though @Catija's linked comment is helpful. Future readers may not want to dig for that though, so answering with that here and linking to that question would probably be better than marking it as a duplicate, IMHO.

Comment: It looks like the `th` style comes directly from [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/tables/) (so no per site deviations) and no support in Common Mark, so expect a couple of 6 to 8 weeks before any progress is made on this.

Comment: @Tacoタコス keeping catija's comment here would suffice as a signpost to the applicable answer. This question is a dupe, so it should be closed as such.

Comment: @Luuklag very well, casting my vote since leaving this question around will likely help future readers find that answer faster. 

Comment: You can't switch off bold but you can fiddle with pure html to make the bold less prominent, for example : `<sup>no bold</sup>` works in the preview (not tested f it sticks when actually posted). Not ideal but I like hacks.

Comment: @Luuklag keeping information for the future as a comment that points to another comment? That does not seem to be the Stack Exchange way of doing things...

Comment: @wimi that depends on wether or not this post stays around, or gets cleaned up by roomba in the future.

Comment: @Luuklag if there's a possibility that this could be auto-deleted at a later date, then I'd disagree with marking it as a dupe and vote to reopen. I searched for about an hour before I posted. From my understanding, most other users won't search for that long. Having this title associated with the comment would definitely help prevent future dupes.

Comment: At the moment, this will not be automatically deleted, since the script that deletes unanswered closed questions after 9 days excludes questions closed as duplicates, and this question doesn't qualify for any other script (i.e. the one that deletes downvoted questions after 30 days, or the one that deletes zero-score questions after a year).

Comment: If you are creating a list of items, you should be using list formats anyway, not tables. There may be a sensible use case for non-header tables, but the examples here don't come close to sufficient.

Comment: @Nij don't think of my example as a list, but rather a collection. Take for example an answer with 100 words that ***need*** to be presented. In such a use-case, a table format representing a 10x10 grid of words would be more legible than a list of 100 words. Such a use-case is *plausible* for sites such as Puzzling.SE.

Comment: An answer that *needs* to present a hundred words had better be a puzzle, because otherwise it seems to show the question is too broad to answered clearly.

Comment: @Nij not necessarily; the Arqade occasionally sees questions asking for collections of entities within a specific game title (such as Pokémon); in such a case, external links *can* be given, but only if they already exist. For example, here is [one such question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386088/looking-for-a-list-of-pokemon-in-pokemon-outlaw) that remains unanswered, that if answered, should probably provide a grid instead of a list due to the sheer number of possible entities.

Comment: Again, if the answer is a list of hundreds, it should not be written, the question itself is too broad to be answered here. Stack Exchange is not meant to be a database of lists.

Comment: @Nij *hundred**s***, I concur; and, even for ***a** hundred*, I concur for the vast majority of SE, but there **are** sites where it's not considered *too broad*, and Puzzling.SE and Arqade are two of those, in *rare* cases. The point is, that a table without emboldened headers *is* useful, even if the use-cases vary.