# How do I extract posts from Data.SE that contain code in them?

Tags: discussion, search, data-explorer, posts

I'd like to extract posts from Stack Overflow using Data.SE, that contain code in them. I am mainly interested in the posts that come from the tag [artificial-intelligence]. Here is the code that I wrote to do that:

```
select Body,PostId, Tags as 'PostTag',TagName, Posts.AcceptedAnswerId, Posts.Title
from PostTags
left join Posts
on PostTags.PostId = Posts.Id
left join Tags
on PostTags.TagId = Tags.Id
where TagName in (select 
  t.tagName
from tags t
left join Posts e
  on t.ExcerptPostId = e.Id
left join Posts w
on t.WikiPostId = w.Id
where t.id in (3615))
and Posts.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL
```

However, many of these posts have no code in them. Here is my attempt to filter posts with only code. I added the following line to the query above:

```
and body like '%<code>%'
```

Does this attempt seem correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that would be correct, but it's easier to just specify the `TagName`, like [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1688450/questions-in-a-certain-tag-with-code?TagName=artificial-intelligence).

Note that answers won't end up in this query (or yours) since they're not directly linked to tags, only through their parent question.

The `Body` column contains the rendered HTML of the post, and `<code>` is used to [display, you guess it, code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code). Not just inline code; code blocks are rendered with an additional `<pre>` element around them.

Comment: I am curious what does the term "<code>" do here? I am familiar with the LIKE operator as well as the use of '% %'. However, I don't understand how '%<code>%' works. If this seems like a separate question, I could post one.

Comment: @desert_ranger that's HTML - I updated my answer with a little clarification.

Comment: We have done this before, right?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379052