# Bolding in the first cell may remove it from the table

Tags: bug, markdown, tables

I noticed this bug in my [Lit answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/24859/5747) when I bolded the first column in some rows.  The preview works (as it always does). The actual post does not, and those bolded cells are just missing:

| Occasionally emphasized column | Column with the word "broken" |
| --- | --- |
| It is not | broken |
| broken |  |
| **It is not** | broken |
| **It is not** | broken |
| broken |  |
| *It is not* | broken |
| *It is not* | broken |
| It could be | **broken** |

```
|Occasionally emphasized column|Column with the word "broken"|
|--|--|
It is not|broken
**It is not**|broken
|**It is not**|broken|
**It is not** |broken
*It is not*|broken
|*It is not*|broken|
*It is not* |broken
It could be|**broken**|
```

Apparently adding spaces or enclosing pipes to the table fixes it, but 1) 99% of people won't know to do that and 2) that doesn't fix the issue that the preview shows the table without issue, which prevents easy troubleshooting.

Comment: I notice the the lines that aren't working don't have spaces between the closing double bolding asterisks and the cell separators.  I don't want to mess around with your post, but I would try changing instances of `...**| ...` to `...** | ...`

Comment: The server side parser likes to have some space ...

Comment: I'm not sure "99% of people won't know to do that" is true. In almost all of the documentation that I have seen about markdown tables (at various places online, not just for SE) the default is to add leading and trailing pipes, including the inline markdown reference in the SE editor (under the `?` button) as well as the advanced help at https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help. Before reading this question I didn't even know that those pipes were optional in CommonMark. So: the table doesn't render properly, OP checks syntax documentation, notices trailing pipes, adds them, problem solved.

Comment: Of course the server-side renderer should still be fixed to be consistent with the preview, both in general and for this specific issue, but I doubt that this particular problem will be very common.

Comment: When having wrong syntax, things won't work. The bug is only preview being too "forgiving", and that's pretty minor.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard it is not actually wrong syntax, pipes and spaces are optional according to both the CommonMark specification and SE's markdown help and the Github-flavored markdown documentation that is linked from SE's markdown help. So there is a bug in the server-side renderer. However I think the bug will not be triggered often and/or will be easy to work around because of the prominence of the 'full' syntax in most sources of documentation.

Comment: Note: CommonMark doesn't include tables as part of its Markdown syntax. Tables are an extension to CommonMark.

Comment: According to the [the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/241919), they're using [GitHub-flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-).